# Removing table rows each time a new search form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following ajax request:

```
if (response.success) 
  {
    $('#search-body').remove('tr');
    $('#search-results').show();
    $.each(response.data, function( index, item ) {
    $('#search-body').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.barcode + '</td><td>' + item.serial + '</tr>');
  });

}
```

The rows are always appended to the table body rather than deleting the ones that are there and then performing the search again.

Comment: Passing a string to `.remove()` works as a filter. Since I assume the `search-body` is not a row, the filter will match nothing and leave you with an empty jQuery object. You need to locate the `tr` elements and remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the HTML prior to appending the items...

```
if (response.success) 
{
    $('#search-body').remove('tr');
    $('#search-results').show();

    $('#search-body').empty();//This will clear the existing elements

    $.each(response.data, function( index, item ) {
        $('#search-body').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.barcode + '</td><td>' + item.serial + '</tr>');
    });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it lets me search once, then doesn't remove the rows

Comment: @CarlaDessi: That sounds like a different problem. Can you either provide more code, or include a JSFiddle that replicates the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** instead of `.append()`:

```
$('#search-body').html('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.barcode + '</td><td>' + item.serial + '</tr>');
```

Comment: but then it only shows one row instead of all the rows in the query

Comment: I'm not really understand what you means. It's a bit blur with me without seeing any demo actually :/